# How to change the default directories used by Nautilus default bookmarks (Documents, Music, etc.)?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory

My computer came with an Windows OS partition (C:) and a data partition (D:). I placed all my default Documents, Music, Photos, Videos, etc. folders in the D:\ partition.

How can I integrate the same D:\ partition with Ubuntu so that the default bookmarks used to read, write, or execute files in Nautilus (e.g., Documents, Music bookmarks) point to directories in my data partition (D:) instead of the home folder on the Ubuntu partition?

Answer (score 1):

Have you mounted the d: drive permanently with fstab? You then could link folders from that partition into /home.

Understanding fstab

http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/mountlinux

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

For ntfs UUID shown is example only see below:

```
UUID=XXXXXXXXXXX   /mnt/data ntfs defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,uid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

Window_names prevents the use of invalid windows characters:
(which are the nine characters ” * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than 0×20) 
uid=1000 should fix the trash problems as well:

To find the correct UUID for your partitions and create the mount point:

```
sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
sudo mkdir /mnt/data
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.backup
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

And when you are done editing fstab and saving it run the following command to test for errors and mount the partitions without requiring a reboot. You will know before you reboot if something is amiss. Make sure you have partition unmounted if previously mounted:

```
sudo mount -a
```

Then you can link folders in your /mnt/data partition into /home. If you already have the default Music folder in /home you need to remove it (make sure it is empty) or rename it. Do this from /home in terminal, the Music folder must exist in /mnt/data.

```
mv Music oldMusic
ln -s /mnt/data/Music
```

Or link all folders with one command (none must already exist:

```
for i in `echo /mnt/data/*`;do ln -s $i; done
```

Another way to share:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Bindfs-SharedDirectoryLocalUsers

Comment: +1 good answwer but we should explicitly say that we do not want the /home directories on a NTFS partition, only links to data directories will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Some info first:**

- Windows supports ntfs and fat32
- Ubuntu/Linux  supports ext4 and fat32
- Windows cannot read ext4 partions but can read fat32
- Ubuntu cannot be loaded onto a fat32 partition but can read them.

**My Suggestion:**

**Split your drive to 3 partitions.**

1. NTFS  partition: Contains the windows you already have that
2. EXT4  partition: Contains the Ubuntu you already have that if you are on dual boot
3. FAT32 partition: The common partion which both OS's can read.

You can easily find tools on the internet for windows and  Ubuntu to manipulate your partiton.

Comment: Ubuntu can also access NTFS

Answer (score 0):

### Overview of Solution

You need to edit the bookmarks Nautilus uses to help you find default directories like Documents and Music.

### Open Nautiles and Edit Bookmarks

Open Nautilus.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, or Bookmarks > Edit Bookmarks

[image]

1. Choose the bookmark whose location you wish to change and edit its location, e.g., change `/home/<username>/Documents` to `/media/data_partition/Documents`
2. Make changes for each bookmark whose location you wish to change